# When user hits back button they get logged out of angularjs application, how do I prevent this?

Tags: angularjs, authentication, session-cookies, session-state

I am building an application in angularjs with a PHP web api that it uses to get the data it needs to run. I found a way to set up the routes nicely and log in the user, but have noticed that when they hit the back button after login they get logged out.

```
 (function () {
     'use strict';

     angular
         .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies'])
         .config(config)
         .run(run);

     config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
     function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
         $routeProvider
             .when('/', {
                 controller: 'HomeController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/about', {
                 controller: 'AboutController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/about.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/login', {
                 controller: 'LoginController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/login.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/register', {
                 controller: 'RegisterController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/register.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/calendar', {
                 controller: 'CalendarController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/calendar.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/newsfeed', {
                 controller: 'FeedController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/newsfeed.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/favorites', {
                 controller: 'FavoritesController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/favorites.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/chat', {
                 controller: 'ChatController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/chat.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/contact', {
                 controller: 'ContactController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/contact.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/settings', {
                 controller: 'SettingsController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/settings.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/personal', {
                 controller: 'ProfileController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/personal.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/stats', {
                 controller: 'StatsController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/stats.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/requests', {
                 controller: 'RequestController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/requests.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/change-password', {
                 controller: 'RegisterController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/change-password.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .when('/weather', {
                 controller: 'WeatherController',
                 templateUrl: 'pages/weather.html',
                 controllerAs: 'vm'
             })

             .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
         $locationProvider.html5Mode({
             enabled: true,
             requireBase: true
         });
         $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
     }

     run.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$location', '$cookies', '$http'];
     function run($rootScope, $location, $cookies, $http) {
         // keep user logged in after page refresh
         $rootScope.globals = $cookies.getObject('globals') || {};
         if ($rootScope.globals.currentUser) {
             $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.authdata;
         }

         $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
             // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
             var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
             var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
             if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
                 $location.path('/');
             }
         });
     }

     function HeaderCtrl($scope) {
         $scope.header = {name: "frame.html", url: "frame.html"};
     }

 })();
```

I've tried adding this like I fond in a few other posts without any luck:

```
         $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams,
                                                      fromState, fromParams){
             var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
             //userIsLogged is a flag you should retrieve from your code
             if(loggedIn && toState === 'login'){
                 event.preventDefault();
             }
         });
```

I also have an authentication service if that would help, though it is supposed to set the cookie for one week.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: I think `$stateChangeStart` is for old version of `ui-router` which is not same as `ngRoute` which you are using.

Comment: Hey thanks! I realized that after. I wound up doing a check on the global variable and forced a reroute to the dashboard if already logged in. I'll be posting the solution soon and if anyone would have a suggestion on improving it, since it does seem a little hacky, I would gladly hear it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added/edited the snippet below to work around the issue for now:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
        // redirect to login page if not logged in and trying to access a restricted page
        var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
        var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
        if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
            $location.path('/login');
        } else if ($location.path() === '/login' && loggedIn) {
            $location.path('/');
        }
    });
```